# How to restart a timer for a task in Celery/Python?

Tags: python, django, celery

Stack - Python/Django/Celery/Redis
Celery config is absolutely basic, such as https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.4.0/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

I have this task:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=settings.CRONTAB_MINUTES),name='get_current_rate_automaticallY')
def get_current_rate_automatically():
    logger.info("Got automatic request to get current rate")
    res = get_current_rate()
    if not res:
        return
    res.save()
```

Basically this task hits external API to get bank rate for a predefined currency, which is working fine.
In addition, I have django endpoint which manually triggers this function to get this currency rates manually.

I need to restart timer for such task in case this endpoint is activated.
Possibly stupid question, but was not able to find anything suitable in the Celery documentation or onsite.

Any sort of help is appreciated :)

Thanks!